# How can I check whether my community password has been reset within last 24 hours

Tags: forgot-your-password

As we cannot reset the forgot password within 24 hours of last password change in salesforce , is there a way that we can check whether the password has been changed within the last 24 hours and show a validation that you cannot reset your password within 24 hours of time ? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

In the user object we have a field called Last password change or reset.

Last Password Change or Reset:
The date and time of this user’s last password change or reset. This read-only field appears only for users with the Manage Users permission.

LastPasswordChangeDate is the api name of the field.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=user_fields.htm&type=0